# is there command for identifying server name windows/linux?

Tags: tomcat, netty

I am using springboot application which is having tomcat server libraries and spring-boot-stater-webflux  library in my application. I read some of the blogs and says that if we have webflux library, our springboot use netty intead of using tomcat.

is there any command for identifying server name on windows and linux box ?

Comment: "Some of the blogs"? Where?

Comment: Do you have access to logs and/or a command line on that server?